# Break from function composition on condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a LINQ equivalent to the following?

```
static T Compose<T>(T source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> funcs,
    Func<T, bool> cond)
{
    foreach (var func in funcs)
    {
        source = func(source);

        if (cond(source)) break;
    }

    return source;
}

// This ends the composition as soon as a null is returned
var result = Compose(x, funcs, x => x == null);
```

Essentially, I wish to compose functions on top of each other, and break if the current value matches a particular condition.

```
result = f(g(h(x)))  // if condition is met somewhere within this chain,
                     // it will immediately break and return
```

---

**EDIT:** I thought of something along the lines of

```
funcs.Aggregate(seed, (x, f) => cond(x) ? x : f(x));
```

but that looks confusing and also ends up enumerating over the entire collection, rather than breaking when the condition is met.

Comment: To stop calculating after condition not met you can aggregate functions itself, not result of its execution: `funcs.Aggregate((cur, next) => (i => { var val = cur(i); return cond(val) ? next(val) : val; }))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is to `Aggregate` until the condition is met. So, I define an extension method:

```
public static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func,
    Func<TAccumulate, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (func == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));

    if (predicate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));

    var accumulate = seed;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        accumulate = func(accumulate, item);
        if (predicate(accumulate)) break;
    }
    return accumulate;
}
```

We may now write `ComposeUntil` as:

```
public static T ComposeUntil<T>(
    this IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> source,
    T seed,
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.AggregateUntil(seed, (x, f) => f(x), predicate);
}
```

And use it in the following manner:

```
var funcs = new List<Func<int, int>>
{
    x => x + 1,
    x => x + 2,
    x => x + 3,
    x => x + 4
};

var result = funcs.ComposeUntil(0, x => x >= 6);
// result == 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely:

```
var funcs = new Func<string, string>[]
{
    t => t + "1",
    t => t + "2",
    t => t + "3",
};

Func<string, bool> cond = t => t.Length == 3;

Func<string, string> func =
    t => funcs.Aggregate(t, (a, f) => !cond(a) ? f(a) : a);

Console.WriteLine(func("A"));
```

It produces `"A12"` a string of length `3`.

To avoid iterating the collection then you need to introduce a new operator, `.Scan(...)`, which I get from the Reactive Extensions team's Interactive Extensions (NuGet "Ix-Main").

`.Scan(...)` works like `.Aggregate(...)` but it produces a value at each step.

```
Func<string, string> func =
    t => funcs
        .Scan(t, (a, f) => f(a))
        .SkipWhile(x => !cond(x))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

That produces the same result as above, but doesn't iterate the entire collection.

Here are both options inserted into the `Compose` method:

(1)

```
static T Compose<T>(T source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> funcs,
    Func<T, bool> cond)
{
    return funcs.Aggregate(source, (a, f) => !cond(a) ? f(a) : a);
}
```

(2)

```
static T Compose<T>(T source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> funcs,
    Func<T, bool> cond)
{
    return
        funcs
            .Scan(source, (a, f) => f(a))
            .SkipWhile(t => !cond(t))
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: It will still enumerate the entire `funcs` collection, even after condition is met.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Done.

Comment: `(2)` appears to skip over everything if the condition is always false.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq - Isn't that what it should do?

Comment: Nope, it should return the final value. Put another way, `(1)` is not equivalent to `(2)`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq - Then I suspect you should go with (1) provided the list of `funcs` is not massive and that `cond` is not expensive. I don't think you'd have a performance issue except under extreme circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

@Mateen Ulhaq - I'm not sure you could see my updated answer (and comments far below) since they became grayed out, so I'm reposting my answer. To see this code run and see what it is doing as you change the int value of the `cond` variable simply:
1) Open [LinqPad4](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx). 
2) Set the Language to "C# program". 
3) Delete all the code you see there `void main()..` etc. 
4) Copy my code here below and paste it into LinqPad. 
5) Press F5.

```
static T Compose<T>(T source,
        IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> funcs,
        Func<T, bool> cond)
    {
        var func = funcs.Select(x => 
        {
            var ret = x;
            source = x(source);
            return ret;
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(y => cond(source));

        Console.WriteLine("Here is the Func that the condition succeeded on(null if none):");
        Console.WriteLine(func);

        return source;
    }

void Main()
{
    var funcs = new Func<int, int>[]
    {
        a => a + 1,
        a => a + 2,
        a => a + 3,
    };

    // Set this "cond = b => b == ?" value to want your  
    // func will succeed on. Since we are continuing to add 
    // to the source, the three Func's above will succeed on 
    // any of the following values: 1, 3, 6 and immediately exit 
    // ending any further enumeration via the ".FirstOrDefault"

    Func<int, bool> cond = b => b == 3;

    Console.WriteLine("Here are the list of Funcs:");
    Console.WriteLine(funcs);

    var result = Compose(0, funcs, cond);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Below is the actual result of the source after being ");
    Console.WriteLine("acted on by the Funcs. If no Func matched the condition,");
    Console.WriteLine("all Funcs acted on the source so the source will return 6.");
    Console.WriteLine("That means;");
    Console.WriteLine("If the first Func matched (aka cond = b => b == 1), the source will return 1.");
    Console.WriteLine("If the second Func matched (aka cond = b => b == 3), the source will return 3.");
    Console.WriteLine("If the third Func matched  (aka cond = b => b == 6), the source will return 6. Same ");
    Console.WriteLine("as matching no Func because all Funcs were applied. However, see above that 'null'");
    Console.WriteLine("was displayed for the 'Here is the Func that the condition succeeded on' when ");
    Console.WriteLine("you set the condition value to an int other than 1, 3, or 6.");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Actual result of the source after being acted on by the Funcs retuned:");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, I wanted to compose functions on top of each other. For the `funcs` you gave, `Compose(4, funcs, x => false)` should produce `(((4+1)+2)+3) = 10`.

Comment: Hi @Mateen Ulhaq. Yes, it does. In the code above, if I change  `var result = Compose(0, funcs, cond);` to be `var result = Compose(4, funcs, cond);` and run this code in LinqPad it does return 10. Unless I'm not understanding something, please select this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq. I like the `FirstOrDefault(` syntax that I used here better than `.Take(1)` as it is cleaner. However, my original thought of `.Take(1)` works too. To see `.Take(1)` working, replace the `.FirstOrDefault(y => cond(source));` code with `.Where(y => cond(source)).Take(1);`. This was my first ever answer on SO, and the one below was downvoted 3 time although it contains the same methods to the answer. I just re-posted it because I didn't know if you could see it since it became grayed out, so please select both of my answers as the accepted answers so my reputation will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
var funcs = new Func<int, int>[] {i => i + 1, i => i * 2, i => i - 3};
Func<int, bool> cond = i => i < 20;
var combined =
    funcs.Aggregate(
        (cur, next) => 
            i =>
            {
                var val = cur(i);
                return cond(val) ? next(val) : val;
            });
Console.WriteLine(combined(10)); // 22
```

**Note**, that loop replaced by chained call, so length of funcs limited by stack size.

Comment: The use of the condition is wrong. If you run this through the OP's code you get `11` as the answer, not `22`.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want such a helper function frequently, then I would suggest you to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427252/aggregate-values-until-a-limit-is-reached) to create it as an extension method, and use it everywhere you want (similar to the hint you suggested, but with a limited aggregate.)

However, if you only need it seldom times, then I would go with something like:

```
string value = "Tes";

var funcs = new Func<string, string>[]
{
    x => x + "t",
    x => x + "s",
    x => x + "s"
};

funcs.TakeWhile(f =>
{   
    if (value == "Tests") // your condition
    {
        return false;
    }

    value = f(value); // reassignment of value
    return true;
}).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Edit: for a more succinct version:

```
string value = "Tes";

var funcs = new Func<string, string>[]
{
    x => x + "t",
    x => x + "s",
    x => x + "s"
};

funcs.TakeWhile(f => value != "Tests" && (value = f(value)) is string).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Why was this down voted? Are you willing to explain?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, use .Take(1)
For example:

```
var strList = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d"};
var str = strList.Where(x => x.Equals("c")).Take(1);
```

[edit]  
Again, the key to your problem "Break from function composition on condition using LINQ" is using .FirstOrDefault or .Take(1).

Here is your entire code per @Enigmativity request / answer. However, note my code does NOT require any 3rd party packages like @Enigmativity does:

```
static T Compose<T>(T source,
        IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> funcs,
        Func<T, bool> cond)
    {
        var func = funcs.Select(x => 
        {
            var ret = x;
            source = x(source);
            return ret;
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(y => cond(source));

        Console.WriteLine("Here is the Func that the condition succeeded on(null if none):");
        Console.WriteLine(func);

        return source;
    }

void Main()
{
    var funcs = new Func<int, int>[]
    {
        a => a + 1,
        a => a + 2,
        a => a + 3,
    };

    // Set this "cond = b => b == ?" value to want your  
    // func will succeed on. Since we are continuing to add 
    // to the source, the three Func's above will succeed on 
    // any of the following values: 1, 3, 6 and immediately exit 
    // ending any further enumeration via the ".FirstOrDefault"

    Func<int, bool> cond = b => b == 3;

    Console.WriteLine("Here are the list of Funcs:");
    Console.WriteLine(funcs);

    var result = Compose(0, funcs, cond);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Below is the actual result of the source after being ");
    Console.WriteLine("acted on by the Funcs. If no Func matched the condition,");
    Console.WriteLine("all Funcs acted on the source so the source will return 6.");
    Console.WriteLine("That means;");
    Console.WriteLine("If the first Func matched (aka cond = b => b == 1), the source will return 1.");
    Console.WriteLine("If the second Func matched (aka cond = b => b == 3), the source will return 3.");
    Console.WriteLine("If the third Func matched  (aka cond = b => b == 6), the source will return 6. Same ");
    Console.WriteLine("as matching no Func because all Funcs were applied. However, see above that 'null'");
    Console.WriteLine("was displayed for the 'Here is the Func that the condition succeeded on' when ");
    Console.WriteLine("you set the condition value to an int other than 1, 3, or 6.");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Actual result of the source after being acted on by the Funcs retuned:");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This example shoes how you break out of the foreach loop using linq if the current value matches a particular condition without enumerating over the entire collection. That is essentially his question.

Comment: `var str = strList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals("c"));`
Works as well to break out when the current value matches a particular condition without enumerating over the entire collection. 
see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) 
and [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you show how your code can replace the body of OP's `Compose` method?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Done and thank you for your reply. It's sad others down voted without explaining they could not understand why my answer was the key to OP's question. It's best to first give people an understanding of their core issue as my answer does. If OP needed more help beyond the key to his problem, he could have asked. 
Secondly, it's best to keep answers to "out of the box" C# functionality and not rely on pulling in 3rd party code. 
My edit is now to where OP can copy and paste :( 
I hope this community can respect "...teaching people how to fish rather than just handing out fish."

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq to see my code run and see what it is doing as you change the int value of the condition simply: 1) Open [LinqPad4](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx), 2) Set the Language to "C# program", 3) Delete all the code you see there 'void main()..' etc , 4) Paste in my code, 5) Press F5.